# Input wrapper div class in CakePHP 3.0.0

Tags: cakephp, form-helpers, cakephp-3.0

How can I change input wrapper div class in CakePHP 3.0.0.?

My code is:

```
<?= $this->Form->input('mobile',['div'=>['class'=>'col-md-4'],'class'=>'form-control','label'=>false]) ?>
```

and it returns:

```
<div class="input text">
    <input type="text" name="mobile" div="col-md-4" class="form-control" id="mobile">
</div>
```

I want output like:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <input type="text" name="mobile" class="form-control" id="mobile">
</div>
```

Answer (score 20):

### For CakePHP 3.0 versions ...

... there is no way to just pass on attributes to a template. You'd have to redefine the appropriate form helper templates.

You can either change them globally by using for example `FormHelper::templates()`:

```
$myTemplates = [
    'inputContainer' => '<div class="col-md-4 input {{type}}{{required}}">{{content}}</div>',
    'inputContainerError' => '<div class="col-md-4 input {{type}}{{required}} error">{{content}}{{error}}</div>'
];
$this->Form->templates($myTemplates);
```

or only for a specific input via the `templates` option:

```
echo $this->Form->input('mobile', [
    'templates' => [
        'inputContainer' => '<div class="col-md-4 input {{type}}{{required}}">{{content}}</div>',
        'inputContainerError' => '<div class="col-md-4 input {{type}}{{required}} error">{{content}}{{error}}</div>'
    ],
    'class' => 'form-control',
    'label' => false
]);
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Views > Helpers > Form > Customizing the Templates FormHelper Uses](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#customizing-the-templates-formhelper-uses)**

### As of CakePHP 3.1 ...

... you can use so called template variables. You can placed them anywhere in a template

```
$myTemplates = [
    'inputContainer' => '<div class="input {{class}} {{type}}{{required}}">{{content}}</div>',
    'inputContainerError' => '<div class="input {{class}} {{type}}{{required}} error">{{content}}{{error}}</div>'
];
$this->Form->templates($myTemplates);
```

and use the `templateVars` option to define the values for them

```
echo $this->Form->input('mobile', [
    'class' => 'form-control',
    'label' => false,
    'templateVars' => [
        'class' => 'col-md-4'
    ]
]);
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Views > Helpers > Form > Adding Additional Template Variables to Templates](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#adding-additional-template-variables-to-templates)**

Comment: This is the final intended way in 3.0. Modifying the generated html through method options was limiting and people kept requesting for more and more options making the code unwieldy and difficult to maintain. String templates provide lot more flexibility with much lesser code complexity.

Comment: is there a way to say which template to use per field?

Comment: For anyone who comes here later - templateVars were added in CakePHP 3.1 - http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#adding-additional-template-variables-to-templates

Comment: @WarrenSergent-spakatak.com I'll update my answer later on to include that.

Comment: thank you @ndm. Unfortunately the documentation is not so clear.

Answer (score 3):

This code is working in my application. I think according to your requirement, this will useful.

```
<?php
                echo $this->Form->input(
                'name', [
                    'class' =>  'full-input',
                    'label' =>  'Class Name :',
                    'templates' => [
                        'inputContainer' => '<div class="full-input-wrapper">{{content}}</div>'
                    ]
                ]);
            ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="col-md-4">
 <?php echo $this->Form->input('mobile',['id' => 'mobile', 'class' => 'form-control']); ?>
</div
```

Comment: This puts the class on the input element, not around the control wrapper.