# How to Install CakePHP 3, Bootstrap and Bootflat without Command Line (cPanel)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, cakephp

This isn't so much a question, it's more a series of notes I took on what I did to get CakePHP 3, Bootstrap and the Bootflat style working on a shared hosting environment running cPanel without SSH access. It might not be the best way (perhaps people can suggest improvements?), but it worked for me.

Yes I could have (and initially did) do all this on a local dev machine using composer, but that itself was a mission (MAMP doesn't have native intl, the installation process for that requires xCode, it got out of control fast), so I wanted to figure out how to get everything working without needing to do that.

Comment: Just reword this to be a question about how to setup CakePHP 3 with cPanel. Otherwise, this looks like an excellent tutorial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Initial Setup

1. Create the domain on cPanel and check it works (e.g. you get a directory listing at http://yourcpanelhost.com/~username/)
2. Use cpanel to create a subfolder or subdomain that will contain the app (e.g. http://yourcpanelhost.com/~username/app)
3. Download the release you want to use (e.g. https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/archive/3.1.5.zip) and unzip it on your local machine (Make sure you download the archive version, not the "release". The archive version contains the webroot directory, index.php and other important files in the zip file which the release doesn't.)
4. Using FTP (e.g. FileZilla), upload the contents of the zip into the app directory you created earlier
5. Try the site, but you'll probably get an error 500 server error
6. If you get an error, in cPanel click into "Select PHP Version" and change it to 5.6 and enable the intl extension then click save.
7. By now the site should now give you a message that cake is working, but you'll get an error about not being able to connect to the database
8. In cPanel click into MySQL databases and create a database and user with full access to that database
9. Using an FTP compatible text editor (e.g. TextWrangler, Notepad++) log in to the FTP site and edit the file config/app.php (which is located in the directory you created before). In that file, find the database section and replace the username, password and database fields based on the information from the previous step. The site should now load with no errors.
10. In the name of security, now's a good time to use your text editor to adjust the salt value in config/app.php with a new randomly generated value (e.g. from http://www.sethcardoza.com/tools/random-password-generator/).

## Get Bootstrap Working

11. Download and extract a bootstrap-ui release for CakePHP 3 (e.g. https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/bootstrap-ui/archive/v0.3.2.zip), extract it and FTP the contents into a new directory called BootstrapUI in the plugins directory plugins/BootstrapUI/ (note that the capitalisation of this directory is important). Note that automatically installed plugins normally go into the vendor directory, which we're not doing as we're installing the plugin manually.
12. Add this line to core/bootstrap.php (note the fact that both the config file being called bootstrap.php and the plugin being called bootstrap is just a coincidence): `Plugin::load('BootstrapUI', ['autoload' => true]);`
13. Edit the file src/View/AppView.php to include the following (leaving any namespace or use instructions before the class definition alone):

    ```
    class AppView extends View
    {
        public $layout = 'BootstrapUI.default';

        public function initialize()
        {
            $this->loadHelper('Html', ['className' => 'BootstrapUI.Html']);
            $this->loadHelper('Form', ['className' => 'BootstrapUI.Form']);
            $this->loadHelper('Flash', ['className' => 'BootstrapUI.Flash']);
            $this->loadHelper('Paginator', ['className' => 'BootstrapUI.Paginator']);
        }
    }
    ```
14. Using your FTP program, copy the files from plugins/bootstrap-ui/src/Template/Layout/examples (or directly upload from the extracted zip) into a new directory src/Template/Layout/TwitterBootstrap
15. Now we need to install the bootstrap assets. Download and extract the bootstrap distribution (e.g. https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/releases/download/v3.3.6/bootstrap-3.3.6-dist.zip)
16. Using FTP, in app/webroot/css create a directory called bootstrap and upload the files from the bootstrap zip's css directory
17. In app/webroot/css create a directory called fonts and upload the files from the zip's fonts directory (note the fonts directory is directly in the css directory, not the css/bootstrap subdirectory)
18. In app/webroot/js create a directory called bootstrap and upload the files from the bootstrap zip's js directory
19. Now we need jquery. Download and extra the jquery files (e.g. http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js and http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js) and upload them into a new directory app/webroot/js/jquery
20. At this point, you can now create database tables, Entity files, Table files, Controller files and Template files, and the bootstrap css elements are available to you in the view. However, there is very little documentation on the bootstrap-ui project exactly how best to format the templates. To this end, "baking" the templates is best for making the necessary files but requires the command line (which you don't have and is why you're reading this post). For your benefit, based on a dummy table called "users" (which contains an id, an email address and a password field), I will link this post to some pre-baked entity, table, controller and template files that you can upload.
21. You should now have an extremely simple create, read, update and delete (CRUD) application that uses nice pretty bootstrap interface elements.

## Get Bootflat Working

22. Now it's a matter of applying the bootflat style. First download the bootflat framework (e.g. https://github.com/bootflat/bootflat.github.io/archive/master.zip), extract it, and upload the files in bootflat/bootflat/css into a new directory webroot/css/bootflat (note the correct files to upload are in the bootflat subdirectory of the zip and are called bootflat.css, bootflat.css.map and bootflat.min.css, NOT the css directory in the root level of the zip which contains site.css etc)
23. In order to get the bootflat.css file to override the necessary styles of bootstrap.css, we need to adjust the default layout which is in the bootstrap plugin directory - but it's not a good idea to modify the plugin files directory. So first, using FTP copy the file plugins/BootstrapUI/src/Template/Layout/default.ctp into a new directory src/Template/Layout/Bootflat/default.ctp
24. Now edit src/View/AppView.php and change the $layout line to read `public $layout = 'Bootflat/default';` so CakePHP is using the src version instead of the plugin version (currently with the same contents)
25. Your CRUD application should still work, but look no different
26. Now in the file src/Template/Layout/Bootflat/default.ctp find the line that says `$this->prepend('css', $this->Html->css(['bootstrap/bootstrap']));`, just BEFORE that line insert the line `$this->prepend('css', $this->Html->css(['bootflat/bootflat']));`
27. The CRUD applications colorscheme should now change (slightly) and you now have all of the bootflat UI elements available to you (e.g. the ones here http://bootflat.github.io/documentation.html)

## Bonus

28. Bootstrap and bootflat assumes you have direct control over inserting the necessary `<span>` elements etc in order to make up their UI elements, but this can be tricky in Cake. There are ways to get what you want, but it can take some searching. Based on this post [Input wrapper div class in CakePHP 3.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24140362/input-wrapper-div-class-in-cakephp-3-0-0) I discovered that you can make the FlatUI's currency input as follows (insert this code into src/Templates/Users/add.ctp just below the password input box):

    ```
    echo $this->Form->input('amount', [
        'templates' => [
            'inputContainer' => '<div class="input-group form-group {{type}}{{required}}"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>{{content}}<span class="input-group-addon">.00</span></div>',
            'inputContainerError' => '<div class="input-group form-group {{type}}{{required}} error"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>{{content}}{{error}}<span class="input-group-addon">.00</span></div>'
        ],
        'class' => 'form-control',
        'label' => false,
        'placeholder' => 'Amount',
    ]);
    ```

## Notes

- Yes I'm fully aware that I have a plaintext password field - this wasn't intentional I just wanted to see how a baked password field would be handled by default.
- The colour scheme of bootflat is not so different from bootstrap, and all the UI elements I tried (such as the currency box above) work just as well without bootflat but they just appear in different colours
- There are other layouts you can base your views off, instead of dashboard. Try editing add.ctp and have it use the signin layout base
- The menu items (as defined by $this->start('tb_actions'); in the template files) will automatically collapse into a menu icon when the screen width gets small enough

## Baked Files

src/Model/Entity/User.php
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/dfe97533f9160b2911a0

src/Model/UsersTable.php
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d532e1bd218a503b7f44

src/Controller/UsersController.php
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/170b8e58ffa8ecbf11f8

src/Template/Users/add.ctp
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c6d4758536649d7ca0fb

src/Template/Users/edit.ctp
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9d689278b030018dc114

src/Template/Users/index.ctp
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/fb0a5cea07c3ea3df062

src/Template/Users/view.ctp
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/cbfb8de8b93d6e59ecfc